# AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque is causing some text painting issues

Tags: java, swing, transparency, paint, jlist

I am attempting to create an opaque `JWindow` with antialiased rounded corners. In doing so, I call the method:

```
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
```

And use a custom `JPanel` which paints the actual rounded corners.

Within the window, I have a `JList`. Whenever `setWindowOpaque` is set to false, the text within the `JList` becomes "distorted" slightly (i.e. it is still readable but it is noticable).

I'm trying to figure out exactly how to resolve this issue. It is possible to set the window shape itself using `AWTUtilities.setWindowShape` but this results in a non-antialiased shape.

For the record, I'm testing this on a Windows 7 machine with JDK 1.6 update 20.

Comment: AWTUtilities is not from the jre, it's seem to me... From where is it ?

Comment: See also http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5354196

Comment: See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/
In 1.6 update 10 and up, it has been available in AWTUtilities. In 1.7, it has been moved to the core API.

Comment: Also see http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1209 for where it was moved to.

Comment: Incorrect answer deleted; sadly, I don't see anywhere to use  `RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING`?

Comment: As far as I have seen, the only way to get smooth rounded corners is to put the rounded corners on a containing panel and to make the window transparent.
See http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=272

Answer (score 1):

Remember: If you use Sun classes, your code will only run on a Sun JRE, but not IBM, Blackdown, IcedTea..